# Formspree form alerting twice on submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am using formspree to have an application on my clients website, and when the form is submitted whether the result is success or error, the alert message is appearing twice.

The alerts look like this.

```js
{status === "SUCCESS" ? <p>{alert('Thank you, We will contact you shortly!')}</p> : <button >Submit</button>}
          {status === "ERROR" && <p>{alert('please fill out the form completely')}</p>}
```

And the submitting function from formspree is this.

```js
submitForm(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const form = ev.target;
    const data = new FormData(form);
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(form.method, form.action);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (xhr.readyState !== XMLHttpRequest.DONE) return;
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        form.reset();
        this.setState({ status: "SUCCESS" });
        
      } else {
        this.setState({ status: "ERROR" });
      }
    };
    xhr.send(data);
  }
```

The form is working just fine, I am bewildered as to why the alerts are showing twice.
The entire application code is viewable [here.](https://github.com/Imstupidpleasehelp/Puppywebsite/blob/master/src/pages/application.js)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out after a bit of experimentation
`{status === "SUCCESS" ? <p>{alert('Thank you, We will contact you shortly!')}</p> : <button >Submit</button>}`
If you have the alert here it will trigger twice.
But if you put it here

```
if (xhr.status === 200) {
        form.reset();
        this.setState({ status: "SUCCESS" });
        alert('Thank you, We will contact you shortly!')
      }
```

It will trigger only once. I am unsure why this is the case, but this is a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

The status is known on xhr.readyState==XMLHttpRequest.HEADERS_RECEIVED and on xhr.readyState==XMLHttpRequest.LOADING

I think, you should do like this:

```
if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {

  //do your checks
};
```

please, check

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange

Comment: Inside of the ```submitForm(ev)``` area? I am afraid to mess with the code in that area since it is from the formspree website. And I don't think that's where the error is because I have used it before and not had this issue